# Dynamically creating noindex meta tags for certain URLs

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to make a switch statement that will embed the following code in the document head when the page is a certain URL:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

Currently, I have it looking like this:

```
switch(document.URL){
  case "url/i/want/to/noindex":
    var m = document.createElement('meta'); 
    m.name = 'robots'; 
    m.content = 'noindex'; 
    document.head.appendChild(m);
    break;
  ...
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to work as intended. Am I going about this wrong?

Comment: Most search engines will ignore your meta tag since you are dynamically adding it with JS.

Comment: create your dynamic meta tags from the server side

Comment: does document.URL just return this "url/i/want/to/noindex":?

Answer (score 1):

Most search engines are going to ignore this since they are scraping the HTML not post-processed DOM information. That said, what you are looking for is more like this:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("url/i/want/to/noindex") >= 0) {
    var m = document.createElement('meta'); 
    m.name = 'robots'; 
    m.content = 'noindex'; 
    document.head.appendChild(m);
}
```

document.URL and window.location.href are going to return the URL path including domain name, protocol, port, etc. So you'll want to search for just your URL path. You can come up with many clever ways including regular expressions to either match a pattern or to filter out the stuff that comes prior to the URL path. You can also use window.location.pathname instead, but I am not sure what browsers support it.

The short of it is that the test condition in your switch statement does not match. For instance, document.URL on this very page is:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977060/dynamically-creating-noindex-meta-tags-for-certain-urls/37977662#37977662
```